# Creating Datetime Column in Database using TCA file

Tags: php, mysql, typo3

In my Typo3 extension ,I want one of my table column as '*datetime*' with *type as'timestamp'*  and **default as 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'**.
 How can I create this in TCA file.

I have given my code below. But this is not creating the column with type timespamp and default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```
     'datetime' => array(       
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:besi_jobs/locallang_db.xml:tx_jobs_messages.datetime',      
        'config' => array(
            'type'     => 'timestamp',
            'size'     => '12',
            'max'      => '20',
            'eval'     => 'datetime',
            'checkbox' => '0',
            'default'  => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

        )
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

The type must be set to **'input'**:

```
'datetime' => array(        
    'exclude' => 0,     
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:besi_jobs/locallang_db.xml:tx_jobs_messages.datetime',      
    'config' => array(
        'type'     => 'input',
        'size'     => '12',
        'max'      => '20',
        'eval'     => 'datetime',
        'checkbox' => '0',
        'default'  => time(),
    )
),
```

#### NOTES

- All the possible types are described in the **[TCA reference](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/)**.
- The field in the .sql file file of your extension should be `int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'`. The TCA definition neither creates nor alters the database. It only defines how the field is displayed in the forms.